# Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))?

Tags: asp.net

When i uploaded the my website online. i Upload the site using cute ftp.
after uploading the site online when i run the site using the url it is giving the error like this

> Access is denied. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>   Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException:
>   Access is denied. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access
>   the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource
>   to the ASP.NET request identity.
>   ASP.NET has a base process identity
>   (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5
>   or Network Service on IIS 6) that is
>   used if the application is not
>   impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity
>   will be the anonymous user (typically
>   IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file,
>   right-click the file in Explorer,
>   choose "Properties" and select the
>   Security tab. Click "Add" to add the
>   appropriate user or group. Highlight
>   the ASP.NET account, and check the
>   boxes for the desired access.

This is the error page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try enabling Anonymous access for the site in IIS?

Edit:

The error message clearly says what you need to do.

Use a separate limited account for the site if you want or enable anonymous access for the site in IIS.

Comment: where i have  to change the iis settings in online

Comment: @Surya You cannot do it if you don't have access to the server. You need to contact your site administrator.

Comment: ya but our administrator don't have idea, Mr.blntechie tell to me how can i go through it.

Comment: Check Figure 7 in this link. http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Set-Up-IIS-ASP.NET.aspx. If you have problem still, your server admin should check the user settings.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I was running a web application using the ASP.NET Development server from Visual Studio and the code where this exception was thrown was using reflection.

It was solved by running Visual studio as an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

see this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6229334e-d5ef-4016-9e7e-1c8718be8d43/access-is-denied-exception-from-hresult-0x80070005-eaccessdenied-in-vbnet?forum=netfxbcl)

Error
0x80070005 – E_ACCESS_DENIED
Access denied by DCOM security.

Possible Issues
The user does not have remote access to the computer through DCOM. Typically, DCOM errors occur when connecting to a remote computer with a different operating system version.

Solution:

Give the user Remote Launch and Remote Activation permissions in dcomcnfg. Right-click My Computer-> Properties Under COM Security, click "Edit Limits" for both sections. Give the user you want remote access, remote launch, and remote activation. Then go to DCOM Config, find "Windows Management Instrumentation", and give the user you want Remote Launch and Remote Activation. For more information, see [Connecting Between Different Operating Systems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: What kind of user is it? My local computer user?