# System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Tags: asp.net, iis

sadly and finally I had to come to this site after finding the solution everywhere!

The issue is that I was developing an ASP.NET website, it works perfectly in the localhost server (IIS) but when I uploaded it to the hosting server (IIS too) I keep getting this issue

#### System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

I don't know what else I can do, since its a hosting server I cannot install any more programs either! [image]

You can see its a database related issue, the only issue with this server I am having is database related, first I uploaded SqlCe but they didn't support, then I migrated the database to SqlServer and it worked fine! And I kept getting issues, this one is the first error as well as the lastest one.

You can see the site here: http://www.aceinternationals.com

I think I might be missing some assembly files from `\bin` folder

The Control panel is Parallels plesk panel 9.5.5

I am not able to get to the point, where I can allow the anonymous users to view the site as the answer was provided in another answer! Here: [Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674493/access-is-denied-exception-from-hresult-0x80070005-e-accessdenied)

How can I allow the users to have access to this site (or database if its database, because the error line is the Initializing of the DatabaseConnection)?

Comment: Consider using ASP.NET impersonation to impersonate as an account that has access to this folder or setup read access to that folder for the IIS user.

Comment: Sure, I will do this thing :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the exception which raises when you don't have access to particular user.You can either give permission individually  and see whether it works fine, its mainly a permission issue because even i am been going through this and getting this issue.